# Can environment variables be made immutable?

Tags: linux, security, environment-variables, selinux, app-armor

With the recent discovery of the [Symbiote vulnerability](https://www.intezer.com/blog/research/new-linux-threat-symbiote/), it is now apparent that we need a mitigation for [LD_PRELOAD injection attacks](https://attack.mitre.org/techniques/T1574/006/) and similar. One way we may be able to prevent this exploitation is by being able to set `LD_PRELOAD` and other variables that impact security as immutable.

Is there any means of accomplishing this, via SELinux, AppArmor, namespaces, cgroups, or any other mechanism?

Answer (score 2):

Environment variables aren't really objects, they're almost like a second argument array that can be passed to exec(). LSMs such as AppArmor *can* filter environment variables inherited across exec, though with AppArmor I'm not sure if it could be done globally (it's available per profile).

Another mitigation would be to maintain your own builds of glibc with the LD_PRELOAD functionality patched out of `ld.so` entirely.

glibc's ld.so already has checks to ignore LD_PRELOAD when loading a 'setuid' executable, so any such environment variables would be ineffective against 'sudo' or 'su' tools. This can also be used to guard 'ssh' to some extent – give it a harmless capability such as 'cap_net_broadcast=p' or make it setgid to a harmless group and it'll become immune to LD_PRELOAD.

The library has to be loaded from *somewhere,* so making all writable locations be mounted `noexec` should help, as it prevents ld.so from creating executable mappings of files in those filesystems and therefore not just running executables but also loading libraries from a noexec filesystem.

It's unclear how the malware causes the environment variables to be set originally, that is, do they affect `init` itself or do they only affect user shell processes. If they don't affect init, it can be asked to start a new process in a clean environment – e.g. with systemd, nothing leaks from the systemctl caller to the service.